# spring cloud config client unable to load configurations from spring cloud config server in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have created Spring cloud config server to include all configurations of spring cloud config clients for my application, the problem is that my spring cloud config clients can not obtain the configurations from the spring cloud config server even if the server is started I don't know where I'm doing below are my code snapshots your suggestions will be much appreciated.

Spring Cloud Config Server
Main Method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class DemoConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Configuration for Department service in Spring Cloud Config Server (demo-department-service.properties)

```
server.port = 8081
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka/
management.tracing.sampling.probability = 1.0
```

Department Service (Spring Cloud Config Client)
Main Method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class DemoDepartmentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoDepartmentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties in department service

```
spring.application.name = department-service
spring.config.import = configserver:http://localhost:8088
```

Directory structure Images

[image: Config server Directory Structure]

[image: department service]

[image: spring cloud client]

Comment: Are you able to get response(s) from the config server directly, i.e. via curl or browser? FWIW - here is a working server/client:  https://github.com/ShadowM0nkey/SpringCloudConfigServerDemo